# How to use overloaded function from smart contract with wagmi?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, frontend

So I have two function with the same name but different parameter in my solidity smart contract
`functionName(args1)`
and
`functionName(args1, args2)`

And because of this function overloading, the ABI of the smart contract has 2 function with exactly the same name, `functionName` with 1 argument and `functionName` with 2 arguments

When I try to use wagmi useContractWrite to call the first function with:

```
const functionWrite = useContractWrite({
  ...ContractInstance,
  functionName: 'functionName',
  args: [args1],
});
```

or calling second function

```
const functionWrite = useContractWrite({
...ContractInstance,
functionName: 'functionName',
args: [args1, args2],
});
```

It seems wagmi didn't detect the function because of the duplicate name and it gave me this error:
`'functionName' doesn't exist in interface for contract "{my contract address}"`

Does anyone know how to use overloaded function with wagmi?

Comment: Are you sure those functions are inside you ABI files? Maybe you did not copy them right, or if they are internal functions you will not be able to call them or have them in ABI's

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the function signature in the functionName field. For instance take this [mintable ERC20 contract](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x9A753f0F7886C9fbF63cF59D0D4423C5eFaCE95B#code) on the Polygon Mumbai network.

It includes two versions of the mint function:

```
 function mint(uint256 value) public returns (bool) {
    _mint(_msgSender(), value);
    return true;
 }

 function mint(address account, uint256 value) public returns (bool) {
    _mint(account, value);
    return true;
 }
```

Using the first function with the useContractWrite hook:

```
  const { write } = useContractWrite({
    addressOrName: ADDRESS,
    contractInterface: mintableERC20Abi,
    functionName: "mint(uint256)",
    args: [amountToMint],
  });
```

Using the second function with the useContractWrite hook:

```
  const { write } = useContractWrite({
    addressOrName: ADDRESS,
    contractInterface: mintableERC20Abi,
    functionName: "mint(address,uint256)",
    args: [receiverAddress, amountToMint],
  });
```